# reason: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs / node_modules

Tags: node.js, node-modules

got error on my code nodejs about verify the first certificate, I'll done install certificate "intermediate.crt" but not working and got same error

ERROR CODE :

```
(node:5500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://dl179.y2mate.com/?file=M3R4SUNiN3JsOHJ6WWQ2a3NQS1Y5ZGlxVlZIOCtyaGh2WUovNVRWbVdZNEpnOVZxajdYbGVwMEtDL0pLbGRqbk1JWVIwR3FkVTRqT0VWdk1rODFqWXlmRTFvRjRuR21LcXFwbEFaazBjMEM5dzcvbXpoTXpyRjZ3SjR5SVRaNFRTQzQrK21JbThYRFc2YVNSNFUyOWtpVG9naHJHTkFGUDZteE9HS0NWcU0wTmpVcjZTckxCaHRWZDlXTzlzdDlzajdXL2xVU3ZsdmNiN3Brc0JnRlZWZFY0amQvWGg3WHRoQUk4MWR4Rmp3aUYvS2VEWDl0dFRPREhXSEpWYW1jcno2cTJDMTQ3bDJBL3J5bWZwZW9BdHlWUkp1VXR5U2VScmJmTFBuckFMb2ZUR05UZENhM2xoSURjdDd4RDd3VGo5NmJpeXQ4WXdVMy9HbzNhRTVSUWtBb0MrZWFtc29sdmxoT2IrREJJMTdZQ3hsdnZPVUV0SGRGTktuc0tHTndXRXlaRjdwL0U4S2twNllwT2F3bXh4YkVoSkw5dmk1dU9rNXhPOVhiUXlOUTNJeGJXNWs3ZUNkbjFYblZzL0R0RENYN1NFMElaN0MweFpscnhpNFZ5Mld1a0M5UjhjMnNmMldEckUxL1FTcVJtYWFmZHo0UFpNSGlHNDVGRWg0aGxVaG89 failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\maceng\Maceng\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1491:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:5500) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```